# When url is invalid Request.get throws ConnectionError and python script terminates

Tags: python, python-requests

As the title explains; the python script is running fine as long as I have a valid url, as soon  as a I switch this to an invalid url the script exits  with a long error message. I ultimately want the  program to keep checking for a connection.

Here is some sample code:
**works fine with valid url**

```
import requests
request = requests.get('http://www.example.com')
if request.status_code == 200:
   print('Web site exists')
else:
   print('Web site does not exist')
```

**Does not work as expected with invalid url**

```
import requests
request = requests.get('http://www.1337example.com')
if request.status_code == 200:
   print('Web site exists')
else:
   print('Web site does not exist')
```

Comment: If you don't want the exception to terminate the program, catch the exception.

Comment: `from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError` then `try: request = requests.get(url)` ... `except ConnectionError:` whatever... (or `except ConnectionError as exc:` if you want to inspect the exception object).

Comment: Please provide the traceback from your example. I don't see a reason you'd get an unhandled exception here, I believe `requests` doesn't throw errors unless you tell it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it is erroring out is because a connection was not made at all, which would not allow python to check for any status codes. Hence the error out.

Try Except blocks can fix that

This will run any code in the try block, and then run the code in the except block if it encounters any errors

```
try:
    request = requests.get('http://www.example.com')
    print('Web site exists')
except ConnectionError :
   print('Web site does not exist')
```

Edit: Added the specific exception

Comment: Catch the specific exception, don't do a bare `except`.

Comment: OP wants the script to never terminate. So, probably put this in a while loop. His statement - "I ultimately want the program to keep checking for a connection."